# Is there -k or --insecure equivalent of curl for azure sdk for go?

Tags: azure, go, azure-stack

curl contains options like '-k' /'--insecure' to allow insecure SSL connections/transfers, is there anything in azure-sdk-for-go or azure go-autorest

Answer (score 0):

net/http.Transport.TLSClientConfig.InsecureSkipVerify